# React: useState hook updates only the last instance from multiple instances of the same functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I click on any of 3 items then only the last one is incremented. When using class-based component instead of functional one for Item component then everything is fine. Could someone explain please?

```
const { Fragment, useState } = React;

const List = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Item /><Item /><Item />
    </Fragment>
  )
};

const Item = () => {
  [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="item" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <List />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/antonfil/qk08srn5/17/
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are creating globals when you do

```
[count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

You need to do

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Comment: Thank You. Really a very simple mistake and a good example why it is better to write code in some Studio rather than in JSfiddle. ESLint would warn you if you accidentally declared a global variable.